# Debugging rails app in production when deployed with capistrano

Tags: debugging, nginx, capistrano, production-environment

I have deployed a rails application in a server using capistrano. What is the best way to debug this app in production?

Until now, when I used Apache+Phusion to deploy apps, I would write debug statements in the code and determine what was breaking.

But when I try the same now in the capistrano setup, I don't see the debug statements.

Where should I add the debug statements? In the code base that is pulled from the git repo? Or the current folder of capistrano?

Also, once I add the debug statement, is there anything I need to do to nginx server to reflect this change?

(Earlier, in Apache+Phusion, I used to do `touch tmp/restart.txt` to reflect the change)

Sorry for these questions, but this is my first time using Capistrano, Nginx.

Comment: You could simply look at the production log to find out whats breaking.

Comment: Unfortunately, the production.log was trying to email the exceptions and to disable this emailing, I needed to update the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was deploying another agent's code, hence I wasn't fully aware of the deployment environment. On probing, I found out that the app server being used was Unicorn.

So, all I had to do to reflect the changes was restart Unicorn server by running `unicorn appname restart`